# No such file or directory in xcode when using React libraries

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I am developing an application in React native. Everything works fine and I can also take Archive release build. but after I take the archive, I tried to build a debug build, this time  I got an error.

> no such file or directory:
>   '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SUNNYCLOCK-bynykhnggpxtgpapfyrgelvatppk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRNKeychain.a'

I don't know how this error happened. I tried following things

- Close xcode & clean project
- Install Pod and npm libraries again
- Link each libraries separately to xcode

But nothing helped. The error stills there. Please help me how can I solve this issue.

Comment: As you clean the project so derived data also gets clear, but still, have you tried manually deleting derive data?

Comment: Is that going to cause any other problems?. I am new to iOS

Comment: No. delete content inside Derived data folder.

Comment: . I manually added libRNKeychain.a into that folder. Looks like its working. I am  going to try your solution also.

Comment: If it is working then no need to delete but if you delete Derived data your application will be in fully cleaned. But manually copying that file is not a good option.

Comment: @PiyushRathi Your answer also working. If you post that as an answer this will helpfull for others

Comment: I have posted an answer, please accept it as it works for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you clean the project so derived data also gets clear, but still, delete derive data manually.

Hope this helps.